# Radio button não está passando valor

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, post, radiobutton

Eu uso 3 radio buttons para selecionar a voltagem de entrada de um equipamento (110V, 220V ou Automática).
Se eu coloco apenas 2 radio buttons, ambos funcionam normalmente. Se eu coloco 3, o primeiro não funciona corretamente. Ele, aparentemente, não passa o valor a ele atribuído para o post. Como "quebra galho" eu coloquei 4 radio buttons, o primeiro oculto (por não funcionar) e nos outros os valores que eu queria passar.

Já tentei trocar valores, nomes e coisas do tipo, mas o problema é sempre com o primeiro radio button se eu tiver mais de 3.

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Entrada:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="1">110V</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="2">220V</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="3">Automática</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Dessa forma, se eu selecionar o primeiro radio de valor 1, o valor não será enviado para o post

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Entrada:</label>
            <div class="radio" hidden="true">
                <label><input type="radio" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="4">110V</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="1">110V</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="2">220V</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="3">Automática</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Dessa forma, eu oculto o primeiro botão (já que ele não funciona) e deixo os outros, que funcionam normalmente.
Essa prática não é a ideal, ao meu ver, e eu já tentei copiar o código dos outros botões (está tudo igual) e mesmo assim o primeiro não funciona.

Os radio buttons, junto com outras coisas estão dentro de um form com post enviando para um arquivo .php que contem o seguinte:

```
$serial = $_POST['serial'];
$marca = $_POST['marca'];
$modelo = $_POST['modelo'];
$potencia = $_POST['potencia'];
$entrada = $_POST['entrada'];
$patrimonio = $_POST['patrimonio'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Nobreak SET Marca_Nobreak = '$marca', Modelo_Nobreak = '$modelo', Potencia_Nobreak = '$potencia', Cod_EntradaNoBreak = '$entrada', Patrimonio_Nobreak = '$patrimonio' WHERE Serial_Nobreak = '$serial'");
$stmt->execute();
```

Form completo:

```
      <form method="POST" action="alterar.php">
        <input name="tipo" type="text" class="form-control" hidden="true" id="tipo" value="nobreak">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Serial:</label>
          <input name="serial" type="text" class="form-control" id="serial" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Marca:</label>
          <input name="marca" type="text" class="form-control" id="marca">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Modelo:</label>
          <input name="modelo" type="text" class="form-control" id="modelo">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Potência:</label>
          <input name="potencia" type="text" class="form-control" id="potencia">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Entrada:</label>
            <!-- Sem esse input a mais ele não funciona -->
            <div class="radio" hidden="true">
                <label><input type="radio" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="4">110V</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="1">110V</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="2">220V</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="entrada" id="entrada" value="3">Automática</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Patrimônio:</label>
          <input name="patrimonio" type="text" class="form-control" id="patrimonio">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" title="Salvar">Salvar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Como vc está fazendo post do formulário?

Comment: @dvd alterei a pergunta com as informações do post

Comment: A dúvida era como está fazendo o post no lado cliente. Está fazendo alguma validação?

Comment: @dvd ahhh, acho que entendi. sou novo nisso, rs. não estou fazendo nenhuma validação, o código é basicamente só isso

Comment: Coloca o form completo na pergunta pra dar uma luz.

Comment: @dvd coloquei o form completo. valeu pela força

Comment: Seguinte, aqui funcionou perfeito, mesmo sem a gambiarra... deve tá dando algum tipo de conflito no código. Para fins de teste, tente alterar o name dos radios bem como no $_POST para ver se há algum resultado diferente. Troque os names de `entrada` para `entrada_` e `$entrada_ = $_POST['entrada_'];`...

Comment: @dvd fiz exatamente o que você disse. mudei o name dos radios, o post e também a minha query do SQL por conta da nova variável, mas o erro persiste. Como deixei apenas 3 radios, a primeira não funciona e as outras duas funcionam. Coloquei a gambiarra de novo e a primeira não funciona e as 3 seguintes funcionam. Não faço ideia do que possa ser :((

Comment: Uma dúvida: esse `id="entrada"` serve pra q?

Comment: @dvd pra nada, eu tava usando pra uns testes e não tirei. tirei agora e mesmo assim o problema persiste. fiz um teste agora com print, pra saber o que o primeiro radio retorna e ele sempre retorna o valor que já estava sendo exibido (que foi retornado previamente do banco), mas não vi motivo pra isso

Comment: Isso irá mostrar um `alert` com as variáveis do formulário.... veja se no alert o valor de "entrada" está correto.

Comment: @dvd cara, trouxe a tabela do sql, as páginas e instalei o xampp em casa. funcionou normalmente... deve ser alguma coisa no meu ambiente do trabalho, vou tentar reinstalar as coisas por lá, acho que nem preciso continuar... valeu pela força, cara, de verdade

Answer (score -2):

Não conheço muito de php, mas experimente remover o id dos 'input type="radio"', deixando apenas o name.
Na primeira parte de código que enviou, a div do form-group esta sendo fechada logo após o primeiro label, porém no código completo parece estar normal.
Eu fiz um teste neste site http://phpfiddle.org/ deixando os inputs apenas com o name e deu certo.